# asp.net mvc list helper

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I want to make a simple unordered list. The Html object provides shortcuts for other types of elements e.g listbox etc. Is there something similar for list. If not what is the recommended appoach?

Comment: Possibly you can use this solution: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8579789/mvc-method-to-output-unordered-list-from-the-listboxfor-method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always write your own HTML helper, to do the list for you

```
        public static string Test(this HtmlHelper helper, string[] items)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();

        sb.Append("<ul>");

        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            sb.Append(String.Format("<li>{0}</li>",item));
        }
        sb.Append("</ul>");

        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

This requires that you send a complete list too it. You could modify it to only add new < li> items and create a  before you call Html.Test. Hope this answers your question!

Comment: It just seems strange this is not included by default